# Best and elegant way to update Laravel model with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function features(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

Feature model

```
class Feature extends Model
{
    public function product(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

ProductController

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product) {

    $fields = [
        'name' => 'Some stuff', // It's Product Model field
        'features' => 'Cool feature', // It's Feature Model field
    ];

    $product->update($fields);
            
    $features = Feature::where('product_id', $product->id)->firstOrFail();
    $features->update($fields);
}
```

Is it necessery to retrieve an instance of Feature Model just to update its single field? I tried following instead:

```
$product->features()->save($fields);
```

But it doesn't work because there is no 'product_id' key in request, and Laravel doesn't know what exactly I want to update.

What's the best practice to update models with relationships?

Comment: just read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates

Comment: Seems like a typo, It would be `features()`

Comment: This can help you [Insert row in parents and childs table laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64425804/4575350)

Comment: @giacomo-m Of course I read it. But the question is a little different. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but you can `updateOrCreate` childs, avoiding the select and update double step:

[Relationship docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)